# How to set grease pencil palette when creating new strokes with python?

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil

Based on [How to add points to a grease pencil stroke (or make new one) with python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48992/how-to-add-points-to-a-grease-pencil-stroke-or-make-new-one-with-python-script), I can add new strokes by:

```
str = fr.strokes.new()
```

where `fr` is a grease pencil frame object. But each time I do so, `Blender` will create a new grease pencil color palette with pink color. I want to ask how to set the color palette of the created stroke. Thanks.

PS: The document [1] of `bpy.types.GPencilStrokes.new(colorname="")` shows that the `new` method has a `colorname` parameter (which may be relevant), but I still do not know to set it.

PS: `Blender` version `2.78c`

[1] https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GPencilStrokes.html?highlight=stroke#bpy.types.GPencilStrokes.new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grease pencil object has a list of [palettes](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GreasePencil.html#bpy.types.GreasePencil.palettes), each palette has a list of colours. The name of each colour can be used in [`strokes.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GPencilStrokes.html#bpy.types.GPencilStrokes.new) or be set after creation.

So you can use `str = fr.strokes.new(colorname='red')` or

```
str = fr.strokes.new()
str.colorname='red'
```

An example script that creates a palette and colours -

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene

if scn.grease_pencil:
    gp = scn.grease_pencil
else:
    gp = bpy.data.grease_pencil.new('mygp')
    scn.grease_pencil = gp

if gp.layers:
    gpl = gp.layers.active
else:
    gpl = gp.layers.new('gpl', set_active = True )

if gpl.frames:
    fr = gpl.active_frame
else:
    fr = gpl.frames.new(1)

if gp.palettes:
    gp_palette = gp.palettes.active
else:
    gp_palette = gp.palettes.new('mypalette')

if 'red' in gp_palette.colors:
    red_col = gp_palette.colors['red']
else:
    red_col = gp_palette.colors.new()
    red_col.name = 'red'
    red_col.color = (1.0,0.0,0.0)

if 'blue' in gp_palette.colors:
    blue_col = gp_palette.colors['blue']
else:
    blue_col = gp_palette.colors.new()
    blue_col.name = 'blue'
    blue_col.color = (0.0,0.0,1.0)

str = fr.strokes.new(colorname=red_col.name)
str.draw_mode = '3DSPACE'
str.line_width = 3
str.points.add(count=2)
str.points[0].co = (2.0,1.0,0.0)
str.points[1].co = (-2.0,1.0,0.0)

str = fr.strokes.new()
str.draw_mode = '3DSPACE'
str.colorname=blue_col.name
str.line_width = 3
str.points.add(count=2)
str.points[0].co = (2.0,2.0,0.0)
str.points[1].co = (-2.0,2.0,0.0)
```

Comment: I appreciate this post a lot.  The new grease pencil in late 2.7x blender is great for artists, but really sucks bad for scripting.