# "Failed to find Grease Pencil data to draw into" when using 'bpy.ops.gpencil.draw()'

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil

I am in blender 2.79b. I would want to draw grease pencil lines by feeding in the `points_list` calculated in a programatic manner.

When used in "Poly" mode, this is the info output:

```
bpy.ops.gpencil.draw(mode='DRAW_POLY', 
                     stroke=[{"name":"", 
                              "location":(0, 0, 0), 
                              "mouse":(451, 503), 
                              "pressure":1, 
                              "size":0, 
                              "pen_flip":False, 
                              "time":0, 
                              "is_start":False}, 
                             {"name":"", 
                              "location":(0, 0, 0), 
                              "mouse":(429, 415), 
                              "pressure":1, 
                              "size":0, 
                              "pen_flip":False, 
                              "time":0, 
                              "is_start":False}, 
                             {"name":"", 
                              "location":(0, 0, 0), 
                              "mouse":(363, 347), 
                              "pressure":1, 
                              "size":0, 
                              "pen_flip":False, 
                              "time":0, 
                              "is_start":False}, 
                             {"name":"", 
                              "location":(0, 0, 0), 
                              "mouse":(407, 295), 
                              "pressure":1, 
                              "size":0, 
                              "pen_flip":False, 
                              "time":0, 
                              "is_start":False}, 
                             {"name":"", 
                              "location":(0, 0, 0), 
                              "mouse":(527, 219), 
                              "pressure":1, 
                              "size":0, 
                              "pen_flip":False, 
                              "time":0, 
                              "is_start":False}])
```

but when executed in console, it is giving me an error:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.gpencil.draw.poll() Failed to find Grease Pencil data to draw into
```

What steps am I missing to activate the grease pencil , so that it can work from a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use the operator**

The error is alerting you that there is no current grease pencil assigned to that scene, and with no gp it doesn't poll.  Have a hunch tho, that adding one will lead to next poll error of incorrect area, when script is not invoked, or overridden with context of a 3d view. [See here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

The operator command `bpy.ops.gpencil.draw` is using 2d coordinates of the 3d viewport they were drawn in. These will change based on the orientation of the view. Would be far better off adding grease pencil using the API methods available. (note add links).  Each point can be given a specific 3S location. *This is what the UI is doing for you, akin to placing 3d cursor*

Similarly to Mr @TLousky's [Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49013/15543), without using any operators  add a grease pencil, layer, frame stroke and finally points to draw a 2 x 2 square on the XY plane.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
gp = scene.grease_pencil
if not gp:
    gp = bpy.data.grease_pencil.new("GP")
    scene.grease_pencil = gp

# Reference grease pencil layer or create one of none exists
if gp.layers:
    gpl = gp.layers[0]
else:
    gpl = gp.layers.new('gpl', set_active = True )

# Reference active GP frame or create one of none exists    
if gpl.active_frame:
    fr = gpl.active_frame
else:
    fr = gpl.frames.new(0) 

# Create a new stroke
str = fr.strokes.new()
str.draw_mode = '3DSPACE'
str.line_width = 5 # default 3

points = [(-1, -1, 0),
          (-1, 1, 0),
          (1, 1, 0),
          (1, -1, 0),
          (-1, -1, 0)]

str.points.add(len(points))
for p0, p in zip(points, str.points):
    p.co = p0
```

Comment: I would want to work in  DRAW_POLY mode. In the code that u mentioned , where do I have to add that ?

Comment: got it. Thanks for the clarification @batFinger

Comment: Cheers.  I always try for an API alternative to an operator.  To find how API works I mostly jump straight to autocomplete in python console and fiddle, then to the manual, then the net.  Consider setting up a class, to handle your gp drawing,   with a class method (for example)  `def draw_poly(self, points, closed=Fase):`  And cheers in that I have a project where having answered this realize the gp would be ideal.